# apprequests dialog not showing list of the friends

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

On the native iOS application code described at Facebook documentation http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/26/android-and-ios--discovery-via-requests-best-practices/ present very interesting usage of the deprecated app request dialog

```
 NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Check out this awesome app.",  @"message",
                                   nil];
    [self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
                andParams:params
              andDelegate:self];
```

It shows dialog but without any friends. I saw ton of troubles with this code at stackoverfloww but related to filters param. But actually I am not using filters at all. And it don't want to show list of the friends. Could it be related to SDK API change? Because several month ago it worked perfect.

Comment: Are you still seeing these issues? If so, you may want to file a bug report with Facebook.